# Defining multiple arrays together

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to define the following in Javascript:

```
var tileXml = new Array();
var tileTextAttribute = new Array();
var tileImageAttribute = new Array();
var tileNotification = new Array();
```

As:

```
 var tileXml,tileTextAttribute,tileImageAttribute,tileNotification = new Array();
```

I should be right. For some reason it fails in the second case, why?

Comment: No, only `tileNotification` will be an array, the other ones will be undefined variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot do that, instead to this

```
var tileXml = [],tileTextAttribute = [],tileImageAttribute = [],tileNotification = [];
```